# multiplication of numbers from while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I am trying to multiply numbers that I get from the while loop.
like 1.1 * 1.2 * 1.3 ... * 2 - numbers are starting from 1.1 and stops at 2
I have done this but it gives me 4.41 instead of 67.04, what is the problem? do I need to write it using for loop?
Script:

```
count = 1.1

while count < 2.1:
    print(count)
    count += 0.1

print(round(count * count, 3))
```

Comment: Well, `count == 2.1`, so `count * count == 4.41`. What's the problem? Note that you aren't multiplying anything in the loop itself.

Comment: I want to achieve this: 1.1 * 1.2 * 1.3 ... * 2

Comment: if I try count *= 0.1 it'll cause infinite loop

Comment: Of course: `1.1 * 0.1 * 0.1 * 0.1 == 0.0011`. If you keep multiplying by something less than 1, you'll eventually shrink the number to zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a final_product variable which will multiply each of the updated count value, maybe this can help:

```
count = 1.1
final_product = 1
while count < 2.1:
    print(count)
    final_product*=count
    count += 0.1
print(round(final_product, 2))
```

You were doing everything perfectly but you need to add something which should capture the new updated value (by 0.1) and multiply to itself to get the final product i.e. 67.04.

Comment: thanks a lot, now I see why it was not working

Answer (score 1):

```py
out = 1
for i in range(11,21):
    out *= i/10

print(out)
```

Output:

```
67.04425728
```